# installing pydub package on spyder anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pydub

im trying to install pydub package with this line

```
 pip install pydub
```

unfortunately im getting an error that says invalid syntax.
i tried the same line on google collab and worked just fine instillation was completed .
what do you suggest i should do to fix this?

is there anything i should download? i don't understand why this is happening its weird

i have uninstalled python  thought it would work but no /:

i only have anaconda. i would continue working on collab but it is necessary to have it on my pc. so kindly if anyone has an idea on how to help please do

Answer (score 0):

You should type the commands in the Anaconda Prompt instead of command prompt. Here are the three commands that can solve your issue:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pydub .

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydub
```

The above line worked for me.

Hope this helps.